# Supabase: Invalid JWT after having app running for some time

Tags: jwt, supabase, supabase-flutter, edge-function, supabase-function

I am calling

```
await Supabase.initialize(
  url: config.api.url,
  anonKey: config.api.anonKey,
);
```

in my `main.dart` and later using this code to call an `Edge-Function`:

```
final authHeader = Supabase.instance.client.auth.headers['Authorization'] ?? '';
SseClient(
    http.Request(
      'POST',
      Uri.parse('${getConfigFromEnv().api.url}/functions/v1/chat_stream'),
    )
      ..headers.addAll({
        'Authorization': authHeader,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      })
      ..body = jsonEncode(data),
    httpClientProvider: http.Client.new,
    );
}
```

This works fine! But if my app is open for some time, it seems that my JWT expires and when I trigger the Edge-Function again, I get `Invalid JWT` as a response.

What do I have to do to make sure, that the `auth.headers` are renewed?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `refreshSession()` method to make sure the token is fresh.

```dart
await supabase.auth.refreshSession();
final authHeader = Supabase.instance.client.auth.headers['Authorization'] ?? '';
SseClient(
    http.Request(
      'POST',
      Uri.parse('${getConfigFromEnv().api.url}/functions/v1/chat_stream'),
    )
      ..headers.addAll({
        'Authorization': authHeader,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      })
      ..body = jsonEncode(data),
    httpClientProvider: http.Client.new,
    );
}
```

Comment: Initially this worked. But when starting the app the first time, I get an `AuthException(message:Not logged in)` error.

Comment: Maybe I should add, that my users are **not** authenticated.

Comment: Using `try catch` doesn't help either as calling `.refreshSession()` weirdly breaks receiving the streamdata from the call that is made afterwards. It only works when uncommenting the line again. It is somehow breaking something completely.

Comment: Maybe I am just stupid. But I filed a bug report for this here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/143239 It only happens when I compile for web, and not for linux. But it doesn't have anything to do with the problem that my JWT is invalid after some time and I can't renew it as there isn't even any session.